# Função para ao clicar em palavra ocultar div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ao rolar para baixo o *scroll* nesse exemplo (http://jsfiddle.net/wanderstone/6pv54/3/ ) você irá perceber que tem um box que fica fixo com a palavra "fechar".

Ao clicar na palavra "fechar" ele desaparece, mas ao voltar a rolar a página ele reaparece novamente.

Gostaria de uma ajuda em ajustar as funções para além de continuar funcionando o *scroll* fixo, ao clicar no 'fechar' ele desapareça e não apareça mais (até o próximo *refresh* da pagina.)

Segue o link http://jsfiddle.net/wanderstone/6pv54/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remova o elemento da página após o `fadeOut`

```
//fechar box
$("#close-link").click(function(){
    $('.element').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Show!! Obrigadão man